# JQuery Element Display / Hiding and Control Flow

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on displaying a progress bar using JQuery during a long running function. My plan is to simply show the div containing the progress bar before calling the function, and then hiding the div after the function is finished. The following code example demonstrates what I am trying to accomplish.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).click(function() {
        $("#progress").show();
        slowFunction();
        $("#progress").hide();
    });
});

function slowFunction() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 50000; ++i) {
        var t = Math.sin(i) + Math.cos(i);
        console.log(t);
    }
}
```

Example on JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/MT25x/4/

The problem is that the div is not being displayed at all even though the function takes ~10 seconds on my machine to run.

If however I just try to show the div after the function it works fine, coming up in ~10 or so seconds after the click occurs. Can anybody help me shed some light on this issue?

Edit: 
Further testing seems to show that if you remove the hide call all together the div isn't even showing until after the function has finished running. This seems like very odd behavior.

Comment: it works as it is have a look here http://jsfiddle.net/MT25x/15/ all you need to change is the settings of jsfiddle to onDOMReady

Comment: What is your slow function actually doing? Apparently, writing to the console is not a good example, it seems to be asynchronous (code after the loop already ran, but the console is still trying to catch up with the `.log()` calls...)

Comment: Mian, that doesn't do anything, he is already has a document ready.

Comment: It still doesn't seem to work if you specify `#progress { display:none; }` in the css, which I had originally. Would that make a difference in showing it for some reason?

Comment: This is a common problem, most browsers don't repaint until the js function has finished executing.

Comment: @bfavaretto My actual code is doing a lot of number crunching, and _should_ be all synchronous, but the behavior is exactly the same.

Comment: I think the answer lies on the comment by @Interstellar_Coder...

Comment: @Interstellar_Coder Is there a workaround / solution to this problem then that you know of?

Comment: You may want to read http://javascript.info/tutorial/events-and-timing-depth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common problem with most browsers. When a cpu intensive function runs it locks the main executing thread and the browser doesn't do a repaint until the function has finished executing, hence the div is getting hidden and shown really fast because both show and hide were queued. To circumvent this you can use the`setTimeout(...,0)` trick, this queues the function for immediate execution. This is not guaranteed to work cross browser and i have only tested this on ie, chrome and firefox.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).click(function() {
        setTimeout(function(){$("#progress").show()},0); // queue this for immediate execution
        setTimeout(function(){slowFunction()}, 2000); // delay the script a little giving the browser time to repaint                           
    });
});

function slowFunction() {

    for (var i = 0; i < 500; ++i) {
        var t = Math.sin(i) + Math.cos(i);
    }
    $("#progress").hide();
}
```

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/azizpunjani/MT25x/28/) a fiddle. 
​

Comment: Kind of an odd workaround but it does work, thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: O.o I know eh, not elegant but it does work. You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Take the code to hide the progress bar out of the click function and call it at the end of slowfunction()

edit: you might need to add some kind of IF statement to determine when to call the .hide() - eg something like IF i==50000

Comment: I have tried that, but for some reason (the same one it doesn't work outside the function call I assume) it doesn't seem to work. I have also tried adding the show call to the start of the slow function without success as well.